# Encontra un numero (b) tales que a XOR b = n

Tags: java, python-3.x

estoy resolviendo un problema de clase pero no puedo con esto, tengo que encontrar un numero `b` tal que un numero dado `a` XOR `b` sea igual a otro numero dado `n`. He intentado con varias cosas como un for de 1 al infinito hasta que encontrase un numero que cumpla la condicion, pero muchas veces este numero `b` no existe y se queda en un bucle infinito, lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna condicion que cuando se cumpla me indique que b no existe y me ahorre tener que comerme un bucle infinito, gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que ayudaría ver el código que has intentado, en la pregunta pones como tag java y python, ¿ valen ambos lenguajes?, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a [cómo preguntar en SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que mi pregunta esta mal porque si habra un numero que me de el resultado, el problema completo me da una lista de numeros y debo hallar b tal que una nueva lista conformada de los elementos de la lista inicial xor b me de igual a la lista inicial sin importar el orden

Comment: Es mejor que edites la pregunta y la reformules

Comment: como elimino la pregunta? xD

Comment: Creo que tienes un link "borrar" o "eliminar"  junto al "editar"

Comment: nope, solo sale compartir y reportar

Comment: Fijate coom es la tabla lógica de xor y vas a ver que si tenes uno de los numeros y el resultado podes calcular el otro número que te falta. Si miras bien la tabla vas a encontrar cual es la operación inversa a xor.

Answer (score 0):

Es mucho más sencillo de lo que estás pensando.

Mira. Sabemos algunas cosas:

- Cualquier dato XOR 0 sale otra vez el mismo dato
- Cualquier dato XOR con sigo mismo, sale cero
- XOR cumple la propiedad conmutativa y asociativa, o sea que a XOR b sale igual que b XOR a, y que a XOR (b XOR c) sale lo mismo que (a XOR b) XOR c

Pues con lo anterior puedes demostrar que:

- si a XOR b = n
- entonces a XOR n = b

Efectivamente, en la segunda ecuación `a XOR n = b` podemos sustituir `n` por `a XOR b` (pues la primera ecuación nos dice que `n` y `a XOR b` son lo mismo). Obtenemos así `a XOR (a XOR b)`.

Por la propiedad asociativa eso equivale a `(a XOR a) XOR b`. Y ya que `a XOR a` vale cero y `0 XOR b` vale `b`, el resultado final es `b` como queríamos demostrar.

### ¿Entonces?

Pues que para encontrar un número `b` tal que un numero dado `a XOR b` sea `n`, basta hacer `a XOR n`